# Replacing part of geometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

Hello I have a OBJ file exported from 3d max. In the file I assigned parts of the model to groups. I can open my file in text editor I can see vertices and faces assigned to 20 groups.

However when I export to js (to rendered on a webpage using 3js) and look at my file I don't see my groups. Can I retain groups when I convert the file to js or does the json format doesn't support groups?

The overall aim is to be be able to replace parts of the geometry with a click or button. My plan was to write a script to replace groups on runtime but since I am not able to retain group names when exported to .js I am wondering if it's possible to do with 3js?